# Pass value to child component and use it as query parameters in Angular

Tags: angular, parent-child, ngfor

[image]I want to dynamically query and display child component value base on the group.id I pass. It nows loop and display group name but I need to pass group.id in order to query the API and display individually the value base on that id.

//summary_data.groups -> are data from the api

The summary data groups contains definitions and group names. I will pass the group names to call another method and returns those data base on the group name.

```html
<div class="list" *ngFor="let data of summary_data.groups">

            <div  *ngFor="let group of toArray(data.measurements)">
                        <span>{{group.name}}</span>  
                        <child [userId]="id" [dataId]="group.id"></child>
            </div>

</div>
```

Expected Output:

```html
    <div class="list">

    <span>1 Group Personal Information</span>

        <child> heightValueFromQuery  </child> 
        <child> ageValueFromQuery  </child>
        <child> genderValueFromQuery  </child>


    <span>2 Group Medical Information</span>

        <child> bloodtypeValueFromQuery </child>
        <child> vitalValueFromQuery  </child> 


    ...so on    

    </div>
```

//child.component.ts

```js
export class StatusListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() groupId: any;
  @Input() userId: any;
  private finished: boolean;

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }


  getDataByGroupId() {

    this.customersActions.getPatientStatus(this.userId, this.groupId).subscribe(
      data => this.groupData = data,
      error => console.log('data err', error),
      () => console.log("data complete", this.finished = true)
    );
  }


}
```

Child Component HTML

```html
<strong>Group Data Result {{groupData | json}} </strong>

<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate"
                  value="{{groupData.value == 1 ? 50 : (groupData.value == 2 ? 100 : 0) }}"
                  [ngClass]="{ 'ok': groupData.value == 0,
                                        'warning': groupData.value == 1,
                                        'red': groupData.value == 2
                                      }">
</mat-progress-bar>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what behavior do you really want to achieve? Where did your <parent> component went? Your `group.id` refers to an array of elements through an API, so why don't you use another *ngFor inside your child component?

Comment: I remove the <parent> tag.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't mention the "<div>" with your second ngFor. This is not consistent with your current html. If you don't want it to appear in the rendered html, you can use `<ng-container>`. Could you provide the html code of your `child` component?

Comment: I updated it with an image to visualize the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to get the group data by API inside your child component, then return this result to the parent result so that it can display it properly?

This seems a complicated way to display your data. I have made a [stackblitz](https://angular-8cauda.stackblitz.io/) to show you how to achieve the html you want with your data.

All that changes is that it's the child component that get the data from api, and display it in its own html. The *ngFor is inside the child as well.

```
<!-- app.component.html -->
<div class="list" *ngFor="let group of summary_data.groups">
  <child [userId]="id" [group]="group"></child>
</div>

<!-- The child.component.html -->
<span>{{group.name}}</span>
<div *ngFor="let data of groupData">{{data}}</div>
```

Comment: This helps a lot, to continue on what I want with my output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Input decorator & get group.id which you are passing.

In your child component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Input('groupId') dataId;
```

call your API & bind the variables

Comment: I am doing that already. The next step is to use that `groupId` to query the API and display back to the child component the result of the query.

Comment: can you share your child component html?